# shortes code for getting the value in datagridvie to textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

hi guys i want to ask how can i make this code below to be short as possible

```
//oForm.txtboxUsername.Text = lstUsers.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                //oForm.txtboxPassword.Text = lstUsers.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                //oForm.cmbAccessLevel.Text = lstUsers.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                //oForm.txtboxFirstname.Text = lstUsers.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                //oForm.txtboxMiddlename.Text = lstUsers.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                //oForm.txtboxLastname.Text = lstUsers.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
```

i tried my old code but i don't know why it isn't working?

```
oForm.getalluser = (GetAllUsers)lstUsers.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
```

any suggestions?

Comment: nothing happen but i know that i use this in my earl college and i'm getting the current data in the row that i click

Comment: What is the value of `lstUsers.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem.GetType()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use dataset in window form application it automatically bind corresponding grid fields to our control(tools).